# Run time exception of android crashing the app

Tags: android

**Hi I am trying to show google maps in my android fragment. I have done everything fine, but I don't know where this error come from . I have tried to change different things but doesn't worked for me at all, Below is the code.**

```js
package com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class profile extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    ImageButton pr_img_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        //AIzaSyAjxQKEZc9MHTH3f173Iv21Gw2c6IeUX2U
        pr_img_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pr_img_btn);
        pr_img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(profile.this,settings.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        if(googleServicesAvailble()){
            Toast.makeText(profile.this,"Perfect!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            initMap();
        }

    }

    private void initMap() {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFrag);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public boolean googleServicesAvailble(){
        GoogleApiAvailability gpa = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int avail = gpa.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(avail == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            return true;
        } else if(gpa.isUserResolvableError(avail)){
            Dialog dialog = gpa.getErrorDialog(this,avail,0);
            dialog.show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(profile.this,"Can't connect to play store",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
        googleMap = Map;
    }

}
```

**Below is the manifest file for permissions. And the meta data and meta data as well. Everything is working fine and have no errors at all.**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest">

    <!--Permissions-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.MAPS.RECIEVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.MAPS.RECIEVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x0020000" android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".profile"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".profile_update"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".sync_contacts"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:name=".synced_contacts_list"></activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDKymeBXNeiFWY5jRUejv6zItpmr2MVyQ0" />

    <meta-data android:name="come.google.gms.version" android:version="8487000"/>

</manifest>
```

**This is the exception shown to me !**

```js
07-11 10:05:20.044 12147-12147/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest, PID: 12147
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.profile}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                                                                                     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:39)
                                                                                     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:12)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:121)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:25)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:35)
                                                                                     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
                                                                                     at uni.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                                     at unh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:13)
                                                                                     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzH(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzwg(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1419)
                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2314)
                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:99)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6080)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:784)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                     at com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.profile.onCreate(profile.java:27)
07-11 10:05:20.044 12147-12147/com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error you will know that 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

Please change com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY to  com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in your manifest and try.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your log you missed API key
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml`

> put this line inside meta-data inside of application tag

```
<application
    ...
    ...>
    ...
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyDKymeBXNeiFWY5jRUejv6zItpmr2MVyQ0" />

    <meta-data android:name="come.google.gms.version" 
    android:version="8487000"/>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: **This is the error now !**
Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1158636114.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #84): <meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?